# Finding words within a paragraph of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<p>` tag and within the tag, there is a paragraph of text.

```
<p>"Hello Lorem ipsum Hello dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex Hello ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecatHello  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Hello.</p>
```

Within the `<p>` tag, there is a chunk of text. Within the text, there are a few "*Hello*". I want to loop through the whole chunk of text inside the `<p>` tag and find **all** the "*Hello*" string and wrap those "*Hello*" strings that are found with an html tag.

Is there a way, through jQuery's selector, that I could loop through all the text within the `<p>` tag, find all the words that is exactly "Hello", wrap the word with a `<strong class="test">` tag?

Comment: You mean, turn `<p>Hello</p>` into `<p><span class="test">Hello</span></p>`?

Comment: I updated my question with an example to make this clearer. What I mean is within the `<p>` tag, there is a chunk of text. Within the text, there are a few "*Hello*". I want to loop through the whole chunk of text inside the `<p>` tag and find all the "*Hello*" string and wrap those "*Hello*" strings that are found with an html tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will wrap all *words* "Hello" in the text:

```
$("p").html(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/\b(Hello)\b/g, '<strong class="test">$1</strong>');
});​
```

If you need to wrap *text* "Hello" use the same without both `\b` in the regular expression of the `replace` method.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EGtBy/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function of the jquery object to get the paragraph as a string. You can modify that string as you see fit, and then use the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to replace the paragraph.